# Boot multiple OS install disks from a single DVD

Tags: partitioning, dvd

Can I create a dvd in order for me to burn 2 or more Operating System installers on it?
So that I wont have to burn Operating system images on different cd's. 
I really wanted to know if there is any program that could make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may can, but not to write partitions as it.

I have a DVD which has 4 different operating system, and if you boot from it, it let's you choose wich OS you want to install

The program you can use is Magic Iso, [check the buttom of this forum thread](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/burn-multiple-live-isos-onto-dvd/168240.html)

Comment: thanks man! but can I do it with a trial version of magic iso?Im still a student and doesnt have money to buy the full version of the software.

Comment: I'm student too... But are you sure you can't use the trial for your needs? It may suit your needs

Comment: I'll try using the trial version when I got enough collection of operating system

Comment: The trial version will only burn up to 300Mb images. Of course it doesn't say that anywhere before you install..

Answer (score 0):

I think XBOOT may be a solution for what you are looking for:

http://reboot.pro/13246/page__pid__115752